# HTML code is working in codepen but not in other text editors

Tags: javascript, html, css

i need a navigation menu in my website so I was searching for some option online , i found a one in codepen,i copied pasted in my my text editors and saw the preview but the code was not running properly in the preview.

Here am attaching the link for the [codepen editor](https://codepen.io/eroxburgh/pen/OJXJJEG?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=98f1a5281252b9c1860042c4e1bf60197a5819a9-1603597730-0-AVTluX0Ws8U-HKy_jMouBjWjYvDxGnfwdfERvV9iWacR4yVtZusVlwoZJjKYLs3Q1YDtugP1WbRnYtiTmBJo_-Q1NClcqVGYxvczKHSHMwpRPhyNDF9U3wk0CpahvUjstovNWro3HtqYm96GPNL-Oogx2xF67gq6XPc-0lnDe-QCjWFrhXQ5sLM6xARyu4Awlfn8vgYx2rNOXXDmpW8cbhpkGArtaa_Tm4CdelR4Z9ImBGK9DXbmpO2m6dNJl3HwwYCimTylZQSmApbDLjYKARVbiYnKOWr6aUhTBr27NDafP-EpRbcAxFfGGf_y7-Yy4LvmJDrwsWDrBHWtoWuhc8ZeQ68ZcPH_TTcgNC_VGrDC) :

I want the same output from code pen in my previews in the text editors

```css
html,
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #555555;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.selector {
    padding: 0.25rem;
    background-color: #efefef;
    width: min-content;
    border-radius: 12px;
    position: relative;
}

.selector-item {
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 0.75rem 1.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2;
    user-select: none;
    transition: color 0.2s ease;
}

.selector-item--active {
    color: white;
}

.highlight {
    background-color: #ff4757;
    border-radius: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0.25rem;
    width: 4.75rem;
    height: 2.6rem;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px -2px rgba(255, 71, 86, 0.9);
    transition: left 0.2s ease,
        width 0.2s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="selector" self="size-x1" layout="row center-left">
    <div class="highlight"></div>
    <div class="selector-item" onclick="selectItem(event)">Chapter-wise</div>
    <div class="selector-item" onclick="selectItem(event)">Year-wise</div>
    <div class="selector-item" onclick="selectItem(event)">Others</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you also add the javascript to your editor? Without it you will get a `Uncaught ReferenceError: selectItem is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following reference in your page.

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flex-layout-attribute/1.0.3/css/flex-layout-attribute.min.css
```